# Can I attach a button on top of a element or a column of html table

Tags: html, css

The problem is THIS table is dynamic and it adjusts its column size with respect to the content in  it so how do i

attach the <h1 id="balanceCCA"....> tag with the start of the credit tag

such that how ever the table and column in it are positioned the balance is always shown above credit column

[image]

This is the html code

```
<h1 id="balanceCCA" class="waves" style="margin-left: 730px; margin-bottom: 10px;">Balance: -10000</h1>
 

  <div class="div2">
    <table class="highlight centered responsive-table">
      <thead>
        <tr style="font-size: large;"> 
          <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px;">Date</th> 
          <th>Ledg.No.</th> 
          <th>Receipt No.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Vehicle.Num</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Note</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px;"></th> 
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="searchResultsBody">

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div class="div2">
    <table class="highlight centered responsive-table" style="text-align: left">
      <thead>
      <tr> 
          <th colspan="5"></th> 
          <th colspan="5" style="text-align:left">Ballance: -10000</th> 
        </tr>
        <tr style="font-size: large;"> 
          <th style="border-top-left-radius: 10px;">Date</th> 
          <th>Ledg.No.</th> 
          <th>Receipt No.</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Vehicle.Num</th>
          <th>Credit</th>
          <th>Debit</th>
          <th>Note</th>
          <th>Edit</th>
          <th style="border-top-right-radius: 10px;"></th> 
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>1000</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
            <td>text</td>
        </tr>
      
      <tbody id="searchResultsBody">

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

My suggestion is to make Ballance as a part of the table if the table is dynamic, so it always to be above Credit.

Comment: Pretty much how I'd do it, except I'd probably go with minimal HTML, for example: `<th colspan="5"></th><th colspan="4"></th>` if the `<h1>` is left aligned it should still line up despite having more available space. (Not a criticism of your answer though, just a personal preference/suggestion.)

Comment: yes that is a really good solution thank you;

Comment: by the way how can i set margin for 1 individual row in a table ___ style="margin-bottom: 10px; doesnt seem to work

Comment: Margin doesn't work but padding does.

Comment: yeah i tried that as well it is doing nothing i am using materialize does that has anything to do with this

Answer (score 0):

Give your respective table header tag a `::after/before` pseudo-element and position it **absolutely** giving the table header tag a position **relative**.

For Example:

```
<thead>
      <tr style="font-size: large;"> 
           .....
           .....   
           <the class="special" aria-label="Balance: -10000">Debit</th>
           .....
      </tr>        
</thead>

<style>
   .special{
       position: relative;
    }

   .special::after{
       position: absolute;
       content: attr(aria-label);
       bottom: 110%;
       width: 100px;
    }

</style>
```

*Note: You can use javascript to change the aria-label of the above table header cell to make it dynamic*

Answer (score 0):

To add margin below the table cell you could wrap Ballance into a span

```
<th colspan="5"><span>Ballance: -10000</span></th>
```

Then add CSS to the span:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```